# Parse string with "read" and ignore package namespaces

Tags: list, parsing, lisp, common-lisp, s-expression

I am writing a program that opens a lisp file, calls "read" on the stream until the stream is empty, and does things with the lists it collects.

This was working quite nicely until I discovered that "read" will perform package lookup, for instance if it encounters `some-package:foo` it will complain that `Package SOME-PACKAGE does not exist.`

Here is an example showing what I mean:

```
(read (make-string-input-stream "(list 'foo :foo some-package:foo)"))
```

So I now I would like one of three things:

1. Make it so "read" will ignore package namespaces so I can convert arbitrary source files to lists of symbols.
2. Use some other parsing library with similar behavior to "read" but that only gets plain symbols, either by mangling the `:` or ignoring the colon and everything before it.
3. Pre-processing the file and use regex or such to package lookups and replace them with plain names, such as converting "some-package:foo" to simply "foo"

The purpose of all of this in the first place was to make a function call dependency graph. I'm aware there exists things of that nature of much higher quality that exist, but I wanted to do it myself for fun/learning. However, I have hit a snag with this problem and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: case 3 will be buggy - because the package name helps to distinguish name collisions (in the case your code uses a function of the same name of another package) so better to change `"some-package:foo"` to `"some-package-foo"` isn't it? However then a bug will appear if there is a part of a program after a `(in-package some-package)` ...

Comment: the strategy a which `read` is following, is explained here https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node188.html

Comment: if you read http://norvig.com/lispy.html you see how to make a lisp reader in python ...

Comment: how about if it parses everything to string tokens?

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, you could handle the package-error condition by creating the required package and restarting.  That would also preserve the symbol identities.  Note that you need to handle `in-package` forms when you encounter them.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to tell the Lisp reader to read colon `#\:` as is:

```
(defun read-standalone-char (stream char)
  (declare (ignore stream))
  char)

(defun make-no-package-prefix-readtable (&optional (rt (copy-readtable)))
  "Return a readtable for reading while ignoring package prefixes."
  (set-syntax-from-char #\: #\Space rt)
  (set-macro-character #\: #'read-standalone-char nil rt)
  rt)

(let ((*readtable* (make-no-package-prefix-readtable)))
  (read-from-string "(list 'foo :foo some-package:foo)"))
==> (LIST 'FOO #\: FOO SOME-PACKAGE #\: FOO) ; 33
```

The obvious problem is that this will read `FOO:BAR` and `FOO :BAR` identically, but you might be able to work around that.

Comment: He could make ':' a constituent character with (set-syntax-from-char #\A #\:) and then find the ':' character within the string if further processing is needed.

Comment: @Leo: first, you have the wrong arg order in your `set-syntax-from-char` call. Second, it does not work, alas.